# Equivalent to Android's "send intent" on iOS

Tags: ios, android-intent

In Android I'm using intents to let the user pick an installed application to send a URL, and I want to have the same functionality in the iOS version of the app. Is there any equivalent to using intents in this way or do I have to implement this functionality manually myself?

If so, how can this be done so that I don't have a static number of alternatives rather than letting the user pick an application that is installed that can send a string to another receiver.

Suggestions on how to implement this is also welcome of course.

Answer (score 0):

Its too late maybe, but still I can tell you what I know..You can use Launch Services to do this.

```
CFArrayRef handlerArray =  LSCopyAllRoleHandlersForContentType(UTIString,kLSRolesAll);
```

This returns an array of bundle names , which support the UTI type you give. If you dont know UTI types , you can check out [here](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html). The second parameter is the role for which the application is registered. Check  [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/LSRolesMask) for the roles.

Once you get a list of bundles, you can create a custom view to show the applications, and launch the application selected by the user through NSWorkspace API's, 
like openFile:withApplication: or launchApplication:

I'm not aware if if there's a direct way of doing this.

Comment: I will check it out to better understand the implementation. I've figured out that there is no direct equivalent to intents the way they work in android but rather implementations as the one you describe above.

Comment: This answer is only valid for macOS applications - not for iOS apps. 
The original question was about iOS apps.